# Laravel middleware working oddly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, middleware, laravel-middleware

Surprisingly $this->middleware('guest')->except(['create', 'store']) is not working while $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index', 'show']); is working perfectly on PostsController. Both means the same logically, so why the first one is not working? Here is the PostsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;

class PostsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
      $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index', 'show']);
    }

    public function index() {
      $posts = Post::latest()->get();
      return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function show(Post $post) {
      return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }

    public function create() {
      return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store() {

      $this->validate(request(), [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
      ]);

      Post::create([
        'title' => request('title'),
        'body' => request('body'),
        'user_id' => auth()->id()
      ]);

      return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: They both should work just fine. What do you mean by "this middleware doesn't work while the other one works" ? What makes you say that ?

Comment: @SteveChamaillard I can create a post from guest account when I use the first construct. Its not filtering out the request.

Comment: Answering your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->middleware('guest')->except(['create', 'store'])
```

and

```
$this->middleware('auth')->except(['index', 'show']);
```

**don't** mean the same logically.

The first code block means "Only guests can do all the requests in this controller, except for create and store so **everyone** can do these requests (as they're not limited to **guests** only).

The second code block means "Only authenticated users can do all the requests in this controller, except for index and show so **everyone** can do these requests (guests, authenticated users).

This is because in Laravel, no middleware = no filter to anyone. `except` doesn't apply the opposite middleware filter to a route/method.

Comment: so first construct effectively means everyone can access the create() and store() actions including the guest?

Comment: To your question, yes absolutely.